# How can i check if 'write' method was called after button click? odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10

When I click button with type='object' write method is always called. I also call some write methods by myself several time and I pass a value to context that write was called from button:

```
self.with_context(called_from_btn=True).write({
                'product_route_id': product_id.id,
                'route_is_confirmed': True
            })
```

in this case in write method I can check if it was called from button and than make actions depending on that.

```
@api.multi
def write(self, values):
    res = super(Table, self).write(values)
    if 'called_from_btn' in self.env.context:
        ## make actions here
```

The problem is that there is one write method which is always called which I cant see. I would like to override that write method call and pass context called_from_btn or to do something like that. Is it possible to achieve something like that?

What I've tried so far is returning empty write method when button was click, but I wasn't successful:

```
return self.with_context(called_from_btn=True).write()
```

Thanks for your time considering my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using following methods.

```
 <button name="download_report" type="object" icon="STOCK_SAVE"/>

@api.multi 
def download_report(self):
    self.with_context({'called_from_btn':True}).call_your_method()


@api.multi 
def download_report(self):
    self.call_your_method()
    //call custom method from here
```

You can directly pass context from **button method** or **write your code in button method**.

This may help you.